# Retrieve File Dates for Files Inside an Archive (ZIP)

Tags: import, date-and-time, files-and-directories

Suppose I have a zip archive file with many files in it. 
I can get a list of the files in the archive with:

```
Import["zipfile.zip"]
```

I can get data out of one of the files inside the archive with:

```
Import["zipfile.zip","somefile.txt"]
```

I can get the date the zip file was created with

```
FileDate["zipfile.zip"]
```

But I can't figure out how to get the dates of the files inside the zip file.

Comment: I can verify there is no way to do this currently without extracting the file first. This is a good suggestion, we'll look into this for future versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know you are probably looking for a *pure* Mathematica solution - looks like it's not supported by Mathematica (yet). However, don't forget that you can run any external program and analyze its output in Mathematica, so e.g. on macOS I can use `unzip`, which provides data in the following format:

```
17:06 /tmp $ unzip -l archive.zip 
Archive:  archive.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  04-03-2019 17:06   a.txt
        0  04-03-2019 17:06   b.txt
        0  04-03-2019 17:06   c.txt
---------                     -------
        0                     3 files

17:07 /tmp $
```

and therefore I can write this Mathematica function to do date processing for me:

```
zipDates[filename_] := 
 Interpreter["Date"]@
  StringSplit[
    StringSplit[
      RunProcess[{"unzip", "-l", filename}, "StandardOutput"], 
      "\n"][[4 ;; -3]],
    " "][[All, 3]]
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks for the reminder.  Using an external function is a great idea.  I'm using windows so I'll give this a try with 7-Zip.